# How to use dyn_cast<> in LLVM to cast vectors

Tags: llvm

I would like to write an llvm pass that contains somthing like this:

```
for (auto& B : F) {
  for (auto& I : B) {
    if (auto* vc = dyn_cast<T>(&I)) {
.
.
}
```

What do I need to replace T with to cast vectors?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast vectors"?

Comment: I am writing a pass that counts vectors used in simd instructions based on vector sizes. So I would like to the if statement to say "if this is a vector, then assign it to (vc)".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast vectors types this way.

You are iterating through instructions, so you just can `dyn_cast` to instructions.

What you can do is cast to instructions using vector types, e.g., `InsertElementInst`. You would write something like:

```
for (auto& B : F) {
  for (auto& I : B) {
    if (auto VI = dyn_cast<InsertElementInst>(&I)) {
    }
  }
}
```

From an `InsertElementInst` you can get the operands of the instruction. Operand 0 in this case should be a Value  (i.e., the vector where elements should be inserted) which have a vector type.

```
for (auto& B : F) {
  for (auto& I : B) {
    if (auto VI = dyn_cast<InsertElementInst>(&I)) {
        Value* op = VI->getOperand(0); 
        VectorType* t = cast<VectorType>(op->getType()); 
    }
  }
}
```

However, keep in mind that `op` is again an `Instruction` or `Constant`. LLVM is a static single assignment language and has no representation for common variables, like C/C++.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.